# Copying SQLite db from Android to PC (and back again)?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-emulator, sqliteopenhelper

I have created a db (SQLite) in my Android device (emulator), I would like to copy it from the device to my PC for easy editing.

Is this possible?

Where does the application place the db file and how do I get access to it? Obviously it is stored on the virtual device (emulator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fire up DDMS in Eclipse or standalone.  Then go to the File Explorer tab.  Open data/data/[app name]/databases

There you will find [databasename].db

Highlight the file and then in the corner of the DDM window there will be an icon that shows an old school floppy disk with a red arrow.  Click that and you will be given a file browser window to select where you want to copy the file to your hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it would be something like /data/data/your.package.name/databases

The emulator typically runs adbd as root, so you can access that via adb pull or ddms file explorer; devices typically do not, so it gets more challenging (but you asked about the emulator).